# ADFS transform custom attribute

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to do a "transform Claim Rule" sending the attribute extensionAttribute1 which we use as the office for users in Active Directory. Do I just type in "extensionAttribute1" in the INcoming claim type: field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - those "drop-down" fields are in fact editable.

In the claim you want isn't in the dropdown, just type it in.

Comment: Can I simply type in "l" in the field? That's the attribute for location in AD.

Comment: Yup - you can type anything.